# Sharing Video on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-videos

If I post a video to my profile on Facebook and make it only visible to a custom list, can those members then re-post the video and share it with whoever they wish?

Comment: If you share an video to a restricted list the share will not appear and your friends will have to either post a link to the video or upload the video themselves after downloading it to repost it on their timeline.

Answer (score 3):

If the video is made available to a custom list only, then the ability to download and/or share are removed from the basic interface.

That being said, there is surely a way for someone who has access to the video to hack and get a copy of it and then redistribute it on their own, but it is not done easily or through the normal usage of the facebook application or API.